# Validate Data jQuery Handsontable input

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, handsontable

Q1:What is the best way to validate the data entered by user in jQuery Handsontable before sending to Server?

I have read this article
[Upload jQuery Handsontable input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10831969/upload-jquery-handsontable-input)

Is there any integrate solution? etc integrating to the jquery validation plugin,if not, how about using the onbeforechange() method?

Q2:What's more, I have initiated a 100 rows table , but it's probably the user would input only 50 rows, if I use the code below:

```
$('#btnGo').click(function() { 
  var rowList = $("#example9grid").handsontable("getData"); 
  $('#simple').val(JSON.stringify(rowList)); 
  console.log(rowList); 
});​
```

the **rowList** would return 50 data rows and 50 empty rows.

How to remove all the empty rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A1:Thanks for Marcin's reply,I have solved this problem by using these code below:

```
onBeforeChange: function (data) {
      for (var i = 0, ilen = data.length; i < ilen; i++) {
            if (data[i][0] > 0) { //if it is not first row
                if(data[i][1]==0){ //if it is the first column
                        //some validate logic here
            }else if(data[i][1]==1){//if it is the second column
                        //some validate logic here
                    }
            }
        }
      };
```

A2:I have remove the empty row by using these code below:

```
rowList = $("#dataTable").handsontable("getData");
rowList = $.grep(rowList,function(array,index){
            ...write your logic here
});
```

Comment: newer versions of handsontable have renamed 'onBeforeChange' to 'beforeChange'

Answer (score 0):

Trying to grasp the problem. If you are you just trying to remove the empty rows before you use 'getData' and send that to the server then...simply traverse the DOM and remove any empty rows.

```
$('#btnGo').click(function() { 
  $('rowSelector:empty').each(function(){
    $(this).remove(); 
  });
  var rowList = $("#example9grid").handsontable("getData"); 
  $('#simple').val(JSON.stringify(rowList)); 
  console.log(rowList); 
});​
```

Comment: Thanks.It's a solution,but if the table have 5 column, and one cell is empty,it does not works fine.for example,$(this).remove(); it will remove the <td> element,if I rewrite to $(this).parent().remove(); ,It will remove the whole row, even the other 4 column is not empty.

Comment: Using jQuery.grep(array, callback, [invert]) to filter the upload array,the callback function can write your businness logic.It's fine!

Comment: maybe it's a roockie question but what is rowSelector:empty ?

Comment: @M.Octavio `rowSelector` was a random variable, because originally OP didn't provide much information, so you could view `rowSelector` as simply being `tr`. The `:empty` is a jQuery psuedo selector that will handle empty elements.

Answer (score 0):

A1: in my opinion i would send the data server side with a `$.ajax` request and do the validating there instead.

```
// your handsontable callback
    // i would use this callback
onChange : function(data){

    $.ajax({
        url : '/validate/',
        data : data,
        dataType : 'json',
        success : function(res){
            if(res.error){
                handleErrors(res.error);
            }else{
                successMsg(res);
            }
        }

    })


}
```

that way you have a way you have a wall built on you server side incase anyone trys to add their own data in manually, and your not rewriting your validation system.

Also one thing to note its best to send back json data for instance in php it something like this.

```
<?php
// do validating here
    // store if everything is good
    // send back error if thing are not
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($callbackobj);
?>
```

that way the results are already in a perfect form for javascript to read

A2: I would just leave them there to allow room for new data. if you look at programs like excel, or numbers they just leave the tables there. And if your viewing readonly i would just rebuild the data with what data you have stored.

Comment: For A1:the server-side validation is good,but my validation method is not complicate,so I'd like to validate the data on client-side before.                                                          For A2:Instead,I want to use jQuery.grep(array, callback, [invert]) to filter the upload array.